# Send more than one parameter per post method in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following code and I would like to know how to attach the variable "credentials" to it so that I can send it and then read it in my backend.
There must be some way to attach different variables but I don't know how to do it, can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

```
postFile(fileToUpload: File, credentials): Observable<boolean> {
    const endpoint = apiUrl + 'api/upload/files/';
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    return this.http
        .post(endpoint, formData, {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
            })
        })
        .map(() => { return true; })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just passing `formData` as the payload, you could try to create an object that contains both the `formData` and `credentials`

Example:

```
postFile(fileToUpload: File, credentials): Observable<boolean> {
    const endpoint = apiUrl + 'api/upload/files/';
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    return this.http
        .post(endpoint, {credentials, formData}, {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
            })
        })
        .map(() => { return true; })

}
```

This way you’re passing an object that contains both the credentials and form data.

This would be equivalent to this object:

```
{
    credentials: credentials,
    formData: formData
}
```